# ¿Cómo bloquear el mail por defecto de WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, captcha, recaptcha

Mis sitios han recibido mucho SPAM, así que decidí quitar **Contact Form 7** y colocar **Ninja Form** con recaptcha de Google, mis dudas son las siguientes:

- ¿Recaptcha de Google únicamente funciona en el formulario? Es decir, si yo hago una petición desde fuera ¿sirve?.
- Me parece que existe un fichero PHP de WordPress que se encarga de enviar los mail (cuando tienes una instalación de WordPress por defecto) ¿ese se elimina, desactiva o bloquea cuando instalo Ninja Form? en caso negativo ¿cuál es el fichero y cómo lo bloqueo?

Complemento:

Efectivamente, acabo de investigar y se llama **wp-mail.php** ¿Hay que bloquear el acceso a este fichero?

Edición:

1- He creado un sitio para pruebas, instalé y activé el Formulario Ninja.

2- He enviado mensajes de prueba y los he recibido correctamente.

3- He instalado y activado el complemento "Deshabilitar correos electrónicos"

NOTA: dejé de recibir los correos electrónicos del formulario Ninja.

4- Instalé, activé y configuré el plugin "Easy WP SMTP"

5- Intenté enviar correos electrónicos desde la pestaña "Prueba" de Easy 
WP SMTP y recibí los correos electrónicos correctamente.

NOTA: Los correos electrónicos de Ninja Form tampoco funcionan

¿Cómo configuro Ninja Form para usar SMTP?

Answer (score 2):

> ¿Recaptcha de Google únicamente funciona en el formulario? Es decir,
>   si yo hago una petición desde fuera ¿sirve?.

¿Te refieres a enviar un correo desde una aplicación externa? Si es el caso, no, no sirve el recaptcha. Si envías un correo desde la web, pero no desde el formulario que contiene el Recaptcha tampoco sirve. Si tienes mas de un formulario deberás ponerles el recaptcha a todos.

> Me parece que existe un fichero PHP de WordPress que se encarga de
>   enviar los mail (cuando tienes una instalación de WordPress por
>   defecto) ¿ese se elimina, desactiva o bloquea cuando instalo Ninja
>   Form? en caso negativo ¿cuál es el fichero y cómo lo bloqueo?

Por defecto, Wordpress envía a través de la función `mail()`. Si eliminas el archivo, si es que existe, que envía correos, no podrás enviar ningún tipo de correo. Por lo que veo, Ninja Forms, permite enviar los correos a través de SMTP, lo cual solicita autenticación de servidor y, por tanto, no usa `mail()`, según entiendo yo, pues no lo ponen en su web, por lo que el fichero que mencionas quedaría desactivado. Aún así, te convendría, como te comentan mas arriba, ver si tu email está disponible en la web, en algún formato de texto, ver si tu servidor de correo está bien configurado, que reconozca el spam debidamente y que lo administre como es debido, y, por último, bloquea las direcciones que te han mandado spam desde el servidor(desde la aplicación webmail/icecube/... que uses) para impedir que vuelvan a mandarte mas desde esas.

Un saludo.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Yo tenía dudas si la función que utiliza WP de forma predeterminada era "mail()" o "wp-mail()". ¿Podría desactivar las dos?

Comment: Son, a efectos prácticos, lo mismo, lo llama ´wp-mail()´ para no llamar a la función sin pasarle parametros y tener cierto control, pero es lo mismo. No sé si podrás desactivar ambas sin cargarte el Wordpress. No necesitas cargartelas con el ninja forms, pues estan desactivadas dado que ninja forms usa envio smtp y no envío por el wordpress, para que nos entendamos.

Comment: Acabo de editar mi pregunta y añadir lo que he probado. ¿por qué no me llegan los mail de ninja form?

Comment: Deberías crear otra pregunta distinta, para que te pueda atender mas gente a la duda del smtp.

Comment: Tienes razón, crearé otra pregunta. He instalado un plugin que bloquea los mails, pero no logré que me funcione ninja :/

Answer (score 0):

El captcha te ayuda a evitar el spam que entra desde el formulario, si quieres reducir el spam que entra por otros métodos, tendrás que utilizar algún filtro en el servidor de correo.

Tu dirección de correo posiblemente aparezca en algún punto de la pagina, lo cual es fácil de enviarte emails. O puede que tengas configurado el servidor mail para enrutar todo los emails que llegan a la dirección a una cuenta por defecto.

En cualquier caso, lo mejor es que hables con tu proveedor de correo y le pidas una solución para reducir el spam.

Comment: Si es un servidor dedicado, pon autenticación al relay y establece una regla en el firewall que solo deje acceso al puerto 25 y al 110 desde la IP local o localhost.